# How to add and return a node in front of the linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

While I'm using linked_list to make a small game. I have a class call card

```
class card
{
public:
    int number;
    int suit;
    static int uniquenumber;
    card();
    void showcard();
    card * next;
};
```

Then for the following linked_list structure, I want to add the card to the front of the linked_list.

```
void collection::add(card a)
{
    card *temp = new card(a);
    temp->next = start;
    start = temp;
}
```

But I can't get the result I want. Also, there have another function need to remove a card from the front of the linked_list, and return the card. I have no idea how to return a node from linked_list.

```
card collection::deal(){
card *temp = start->next;
start->next = nullptr;
start = temp;
return start;
}
```

This way will just return me an error saying "can't convert "card *" to "card" "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Adding

Time for a walk-through:

```
void collection::add(card a) // pass by value. a is a copy 
{
    card *temp = new card(a); // makes a dynamically allocated copy of the copy.
    temp->next = start; // looks right
    start = temp; // looks right
}
```

There is nothing explicitly wrong in this function, but if you want

```
myCollection.add(mycard);
```

and then expect to use `mycard` as though it is in `myCollection`, you are out of luck. A copy of `mycard` is in `mycollection`. We can make slight improvements to reduce the amount of copying,

```
void collection::add(const card & a) // pass by reference. a is the source. One less copy
                                     // Look up const correctness for more information 
                                     // on the use of const here 
{
    card *temp = new card(a); // makes a dynamically allocated copy of the copy.
    temp->next = start; 
    start = temp;
}
```

but if you want `mycard` to be in the list rather than a copty of it, you need to do things very differently

```
void collection::add(card * a) // pass by reference via a pointer
{
    a->next = start;
    start = a;
}
```

and use it something like:

```
card * mycard = new card()
// set members of *mycard. Or better, make a smarter constructor to set them for you
myCollection.add(mycard);
```

## Removal

```
card collection::deal(){
    card *temp = start->next; //temp points to the second item on the list
    start->next = nullptr; // cur off start from the rest of the list
    start = temp; // whups! Just lost the first item in the list
    return start; // start is a pointer. The return type is not. Need to dereference
}
```

Fix one: deference the pointer to return it.

```
card collection::deal(){
    card *temp = start->next; 
    start->next = nullptr; 
    start = temp; 
    return *start; // returns a copy of the second card in the list
}
```

Next fix: return the correct card

```
card collection::deal(){
    card *temp = start; //temp points to the first item on the list
    start = start->next; // advance start to second item on the list
    temp->next = nullptr; // cut former first item off from from the list
    return *temp; // returns a copy of the former first item. But what of temp?
}
```

Next fix: `temp` was leaked. No one points to it and the memory was never freed.

```
card collection::deal(){
    card *temp = start; 
    start = start->next; 
    temp->next = nullptr; 
    card rval(*temp); // copy former first node
    delete temp; // free former first node
    return rval; // return copy.
}
```

You could also return a pointer to the item removed and leave freeing it to the caller. This is a bit dodgy.

```
card * collection::deal(){
    card *temp = start; //temp points to the first item on the list
    start = start->next; // advance start to second item on the list
    temp->next = nullptr; // cut former first item off from from the list
    return temp; // returns former first item 
}
```

[Look into `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as a tool to ensure that returned `card` pointers are released by the caller.

Another possibility is to separate the linked list from the `card` This way `collection`'s users only see `card`s and have no clue how the `card`s are stored inside `collection`.

Comment: In the first rewrite of `add()`, why do you pass argument by non-const ref?

Comment: Thanks for the fix, Remy.  @bipll I didn't want to open up another can of worms explaining the whys and hows of something tangential. I felt like I already had too much going on, so I just left a comment with a key term an asker could look up if they were interested.

Comment: And on second thought, you're right @bipll . The explanation can go either way, so it's probably better that I use `const` and recommend they look up why on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add()` looks fine, but your `deal()` is all wrong. It should look more like this instead:

```
card collection::deal()
{
    if (!start) throw std::runtime_error("deck is empty!");
    card *temp = start;
    start = temp->next;
    card theCard = *temp;
    c.next = nullptr;
    delete temp;
    return theCard;
}
```

You can simplify the code a bit by using some more creative coding, eg:

```
class card
{
public:
    int number;
    int suit;
    card * next;

    static int uniquenumber;

    card();
    card(const card &src, card *n = nullptr);
    card& operator=(const card &rhs);

    void showcard();
};
```

```
#include <memory>

card::card()
    : number(0), suit(0), next(nullptr)
{
}

card::card(const card &src, card *n)
    : number(src.number), suit(src.suit), next(n)
{
}

card& card::operator=(const card &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        number = rhs.number;
        suit = rhs.suit;
        // don't copy 'next'!
        next = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

void collection::add(const card &a)
{
    start = new card(a, start);
}

card collection::deal()
{
    if (!start) throw std::runtime_error("deck is empty!");
    std::unique_ptr<card> temp(start);
    start = start->next;
    return *temp;
}
```

But, that being said, from a design perspective, `card` really should not have a `next` member at all.  You should separate `card` from the implementation of the linked list (which would, in turn, allow you to change the implementation of the list at a later time without having to change `card` to match).  You want a list that *contains* card objects, not a list that *is* card objects.

You should use `std::list` for that separation, eg:

```
#include <list>

class card
{
public:
    int number;
    int suit;

    static int uniquenumber;

    card();
    void showcard();
};

class collection
{
private:
    std::list<card> cards;

public:
    void add(const card &a);
    card deal();
};
```

```
void collection::add(const card &a)
{
    cards.push_front(a);
}

card collection::deal()
{
    if (cards.empty()) throw std::runtime_error("deck is empty!");
    card theCard = cards.front();
    cards.pop_front();
    return theCard;
}
```

But, if you can't use `std::list`, then you can use something more like this:

```
class card
{
public:
    int number;
    int suit;

    static int uniquenumber;

    card();
    void showcard();
};

class collection
{
private:
    struct collectionItem
    {
        card theCard;
        collectionItem *next;

        collectionItem(const card &a, collectionItem *n);
    };

    collectionItem *start;

public:
    collection();
    ~collection();

    void add(const card &a);
    card deal();
};
```

```
#include <memory>

collection::collection()
    : start(nullptr)
{
}

collection::collectionItem::collectionItem(const card &a, collectionItem *n)
    : theCard(a), next(n)
{
}

collection::~collection()
{
    collectionItem *item = start;
    while (item)
        item = std::unique_ptr<collectionItem>(item)->next;
}

void collection::add(const card &a)
{
    start = new collectionItem(a, start);
}

card collection::deal()
{
    if (!start) throw std::runtime_error("deck is empty!");
    std::unique_ptr<collectionItem> temp(start);
    start = temp->next;
    return temp->theCard;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pointer variable, you can get the actual value referenced by the pointer dereferencing the pointer.

try `return *start;`

Comment: This won't satisfy the requirements given: "*remove a card from the front of the linked_list, and return the card*".  If you just `return` the dereferenced pointer, you aren't removing the `card` from the list.  If you remove the `card` from the list, you still have to destroy it, so you can't dereference it and destroy it at the same time. You would have to make a *copy* of the `card`, destroy the `card` in the list, and then `return` the copy.